# NUnit does not find tests

Tags: c#, msbuild, mono, nunit

I tried to set up a project using Mono, C#, and NUnit.

I tried to get tests running, so I build a MSBuild/xbuild `Test.csproj` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <OutputPath>bin</OutputPath>
    <AssemblyName>Test</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="nunit.framework">
      <HintPath>..\packages\NUnit\lib\net45\nunit.framework.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Test.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <ItemGroup>
   <ProjectReference Include="..\mainproj.csproj">
    <Name>Mainproj</Name>
   </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I built this project using `xbuild Test.csproj`.

The file `Test.cs` does contain two simple tests:

```
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace Foo.Test {

    [TestFixture]
    public class TestClass
    {
        [TestCase]
        public void AddTest()
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(30, 15 + 15);
        }

        [TestCase]
        public void Minus()
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(30, 15 - 15);
        }
    }
}
```

### What works?

- The Test.dll is compiled successfully

### What does not work

`nunit-console4 bin/nunit.framework.dll bin/Test.dll` does not find any tests:

```
NUnit version 2.4.8
Copyright (C) 2002-2007 Charlie Poole.
Copyright (C) 2002-2004 James W. Newkirk, Michael C. Two, Alexei A. Vorontsov.
Copyright (C) 2000-2002 Philip Craig.
All Rights Reserved.

Runtime Environment -
   OS Version: Unix 15.0.0.0
  CLR Version: 4.0.30319.17020 ( 4.2.1 (Stable 4.2.1.102/6dd2d0d Wed Dec  2 14:02:18 PST 2015) )

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Not run: 0, Time: 0.055 seconds
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Name your test case attributes "Test" (not "TestCase"):

### Updated Code:

```
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace Foo.Test {

    [TestFixture ()]
    public class TestClass
    {
        [Test ()]
        public void AddTest()
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(30, 15 + 15);
        }

        [Test ()]
        public void Minus()
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(30, 15 - 15);
        }
    }
}
```

### Example output of your tests:

```
$> nunit-console4 Test.dll

NUnit version 2.4.8
~~~~
..F
Tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Not run: 0, Time: 0.120 seconds

Test Case Failures:
1) Foo.Test.TestClass.Minus :   Expected: 30
```

Note: There is no reason to pass the `nunit.framework.dll` to `nunit-console4` as it will been scanned for tests which there are not any.

Ref: http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=test&r=2.6.4

Comment: Great, that was the issue. Btw. is there a difference between `[Test]` and `[Test ()]`, it seems that `[Test]` works just fine so I figure that it will implicitly call `Test ()`

Comment: [Test] works fine, it is habit for me... i.e. [Test (ExpectedResult = "StackOverflow")], plus my code formatter adds it if it is missing... ;-)